# How does Django know which location the user is from?

Tags: python, django, localization

I am reading the Django localization documentation:http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/localization/

Of course, where the user is from determines what "message file" to use.

How do I determine where the user is from and what to use? Does it do it automatically?

Answer (score 2):

You can add [Locale middleware](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/#module-django.middleware.locale) to your [MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#topics-http-middleware) in settings if you want to enable language selection based on data from the request in Django.

Read [how Django discovers language preference](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/deployment/#id1) to learn details.

[From docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/deployment/#id1)

> LocaleMiddleware tries to determine
>   the user's language preference by
>   following this algorithm:
>
> - First, it looks for a django_language key in the current
>     user's session.
> - Failing that, it looks for a cookie.
> - Failing that, it looks at the Accept-Language HTTP header. This
>     header is sent by your browser and
>     tells the server which language(s) you
>     prefer, in order by priority. Django
>     tries each language in the header
>     until it finds one with available
>     translations.
> - Failing that, it uses the global LANGUAGE_CODE setting.

Answer (score 0):

Language option shouldn't be based on the location of the user but rather on browser setting or explicit setting on page because location doesn't define people's languages.